# Have Flask read file from disk and send it to user

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a very simple problem that I don't seem to be able to understand.

I have a simple Flask application. I want to read an XML file from disk and send it to the user but Flask keeps returning 404. This is my code:

```
@app.route('/update.php')
@app.route('/update')
def send_sparkle_xml():
    """ Send the Sparkle XML file if someone does a GET on the update URL. """

    return send_from_directory(directory='files', filename='updates.xml')
```

`updates.xml` exists in a directory called `files` on the same level as the script displayed. I just keep getting 404, don't know why.

Comment: I've just recreated the same code in flask sample app and it works fine for me, I don't get 404, I'm using flask 0.10.

Comment: Nope, can't make it work. Same version of Flask.

Comment: Is the request reaching the send_sparkle_xml method?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that.

Comment: try an absolute path to the directory?

Comment: Did you have file in `<app_root>/files/updates.xml`? Could it be that apache, nginx or etc handle your url?

Comment: @crewburn, can you put that in an answer so I can accept it?